# Difference between `ref` and `innerRef` in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am using two class components where I have a method that I am invoking from the parent component. and for this reason, I have to create two references using `React.createRef()`. But the problem is one component allows me with `ref` attribute and another `innerRef` attribute. So I want to know what is the difference.

```
class X extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.xRef = React.createRef();
    this.yRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Xcomponent
        classes={classes}
        user={user}
        ref={this.xRef}
      />
      <Ycomponent
        classes={classes}
        user={user}
        innerRef={this.xRef}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `innerRef` isn't a standard React property. It must be a `prop` that is used by `Ycomponent`

Comment: Are you using Material UI? In `innerRef` is a legacy feature that was used in MuiV3 [See here.](https://v3.mui.com/css-in-js/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component)

Answer (score 5):

`innerRef` is a [component instance property](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#props), while `ref` is a [component instance attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs):

> When the ref attribute is a callback function, the function receives the underlying DOM element or class instance.

```
// Access reference within the parent component: this.xRef.current
// Access property within the component: this.props.innerRef.current
<Ycomponent ref={this.xRef} innerRef={this.xRef} />


// coolRef is an ordinary component property, you can name it as you like
<Ycomponent ref={this.xRef} coolRef={this.xRef} />
// access with this.props.coolRef.current within the component.
```

In conclusion, the custom component `Ycomponent` defines the property `innerRef` for the developer to pass a reference with it.

For more info see related question: [Why, exactly, do we need React.forwardRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931842/7882470)